# Is there a way to reduce the processing time of a pixelseparator code?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to convert an image into a set of arrays that can be useful for digital processing and analytics for commercial purposes. A code has already been created and it works, but is there any way to reduce the time taken for the code to be executed?

This is a final stage for the commercialisation of a new form of technology that will need to take into account real time analysis of images taken by the technology.

```
function pixelseperator()

clear all

close all
Image=imread('flirpolarcamtest3.png');


Image=uint16(Image);
[m,n]=size(Image);
Imagex=zeros(m/2,n/2);
Imagexrows=zeros((m/2),1);
col=1;
for ni=1:2:n-1
    row=1;
    for mi=1:2:m-1
      Imagexrows(row)=Image(mi,ni);
      row=row+1;   
    end
col=col+1;    
Imagex(:,col)=Imagexrows;
end
Image0=Imagex;
```

The average time taken for the code to be actuated was apprximately 0.74 seconds, which was expected but a bit too long for the desired time and contained a bit too many intermediates making the code a bit redundant. I am looking for a way to cut down on redundancues and hence reduce the time taken for processing.

Comment: You can start by removing `clear all` and `close all` from your function. Those should never appear in a function, because they affect all of the session, not just the function. They also slow down execution significantly. Also, you don't return anything from the function, so I guess you can speed it up by deleting all the code inside... :p

Answer (score 0):

Your code is identical to:

```
Image = imread('flirpolarcamtest3.png');
Image0 = uint16(Image(1:2:end-1,1:2:end-1));
```

I don't know why your loops go to `n-1` and `m-1`, rather than `n` and `m`. For even-sized images these would be the same, but for odd-sized images, you'd miss one row and one column using your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there anything else I may need to know?